# XML mapping with Jackson no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('Belgian Waffles')

Tags: java, xml, jackson

for learning purposes I am trying to map xml file to pojo. My xml looks like this:

```
<breakfast_menu>
   <food>
     <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
     <price>$5.95</price>
     <description>
        Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup
     </description>
     <calories>650</calories>
   </food>
   <food>
     <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
     <price>$7.95</price>
     <description>
        Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream
     </description>
     <calories>900</calories>
   </food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

Breakfes entity class

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "breakfast_menu")
public class BreakfestFood {

    private List<Food> food;

    public BreakfestFood() {}

    public List<Food> getFood() {
        return food;
    }

    public void setFood(List<Food> food) {
        this.food = food;
    }

}
```

Food entity class

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "food")
public class Food {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "name")
    private String name;
    @JacksonXmlProperty
    private double price;
    @JacksonXmlProperty
    private String description;
    @JacksonXmlProperty
    private int calories;
```

And main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("X:\\food.xml");
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();

    try {
        String xml = inputStreamToString(new FileInputStream(file));
        BreakfestFood value = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, BreakfestFood.class);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I am running this code I am getting stack like this: 
String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('Belgian Waffles'). So it seems it cannot map name value of the Food. Anyone has idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mapping is incorrect.
To check what is wrong, I encourage you to serialize a simple object.

```
BreakfestFood bf = new BreakfestFood();
Food f1 = new Food();
f1.setName("f1Name");
f1.setCalories(20);
f1.setDescription("desc");
f1.setPrice(11.1);
bf.setFood(List.of(f1));

System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(bf));

Output: 
<breakfast_menu>
  <food>
    <food>
      <price>11.1</price>
      <description>desc</description>
      <calories>20</calories>
      <name>f1Name</name>
    </food>
  </food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

As you can see, you get an extra wrapper for the list.
To get rid of it, use:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "breakfast_menu")
public class BreakfestFood {

    // Use this to change element name:
    // @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "food")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Food> food;

    // getters and setters
}
```

On top of that:

- annotations in Food are redundant if you have public getters
- the values in price tag are not doubles. You'll need to adjust the mapping to parse the currency values. Custom `@JsonSerialize` and `@JsonDeserialize` are one idea to tackle this.
- more generally, storing prices as doubles is a poor idea.